# Using libspotify SDK to authenticate free accounts

Tags: spotify, user-accounts

We have an iOS application that uses libspotify to authenticate Spotify users and access their playlists and music.

This works great for Spotify Premium users, but we've noticed that Spotify Free users (a class that launched fairly recently) cannot authenticate with their credentials.

I couldn't find anything in their docs that referred to this - does anyone know if it is possible to authenticate free users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not. As you should be able to see, the error `SP_ERROR_USER_NEEDS_PREMIUM` is thrown if you try to log in with a free user.

Comment: yep, i saw that. but I was hoping that there was a different way to authenticate free users that they just hadn't got around to documenting. thanks!